# Error en Conexión MySQL y Java: Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password'

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Al intentar hacer una conexión MySQL me arroja el siguiente error:

> `run:
>   feb 01, 2020 9:15:37 PM functions.databaseConnection connectionDB
>   java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password'.
>   null
>   GRAVE: null
>   java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password'.
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:923)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1725)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1250)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2465)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2498)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2283)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:822)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:404)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
>       at functions.databaseConnection.connectionDB(databaseConnection.java:53)
>       at functions.databaseConnection.readProperties(databaseConnection.java:42)
>       at inventarioalmacenapp.InventarioAlmacenApp.main(InventarioAlmacenApp.java:22)`

**Clase `databaseConnection.java`**

```
package functions;



import java.io.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.*;
import lists.propertiesConnection;


public class databaseConnection {
Properties prop = new Properties();

/**
 *
 */
public static Connection connDB = null;
/**  
 * Metodo que lee el archivo settings.properties
 * @return una Lista de Objetos con los valores del Archivo settingsApp.properties
 */
public List<propertiesConnection> readProperties(){
    List<propertiesConnection> listProperties = new ArrayList<>();
    propertiesConnection _prop;
    try {
        prop.load(prop.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/.settings/settingsApp.properties"));
        _prop = new propertiesConnection(prop.getProperty("user_DB"),prop.getProperty("password_DB"),prop.getProperty("server_DB"), prop.getProperty("dataBase"), prop.getProperty("portServer"));
        listProperties.add(_prop);  
        connectionDB(_prop.getNameUser(), _prop.getUserPassword(), _prop.getServer(), _prop.getDbName(), _prop.getPortServer());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(databaseConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  return listProperties ;  
}

public static Connection connectionDB(String user_DB, String userPassword, String serverDB, String dbName, String portServer){
    if(connDB==null){           
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connDB = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/stockinventory", "user", "password");
            System.out.println("Connection Success");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(databaseConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }else{

    }
    System.out.println(connDB);
    return connDB;
}
```

**Libreria JDBC**

[image: Libreria]

Es la primera vez que me aparece este error y no logro dar con la solución.

Comment: Usas Maven? ayuda mucho a gestionar los recursos.

Comment: No uso maven, ya había trabajado con jdbc, pero no me marcaba ese error.

Comment: En la traza del error se repite varias veces este mensaje: `Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password'` Parece que intentas usar un plugin que no existe. ¿Necesitas realmente de ese plugin para conectar a tu base de datos? Entonces debes revisar que esté instalado y activado. Si no lo necesitas entonces crea un código de conexión que no dependa de él.

Comment: El problema es que no he instalado nada, lo único que agregué fue el conector. Siempre he hecho la conexión de esa forma, pero ahora me marca ese error.

Comment: No utilizo ningún plugin, he hecho la conexión como tradicionalmente la desarrollo, solo que, esta vez me marca ese error.

Comment: El error es muy claro, y habla varias de un plugin. Puede que el problema esté a nivel del conector de bases de datos o en tu versión de MySQL. Revisa las respuestas a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49194719/5587982).

Comment: He visto que tal vez este en la versión de MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solución**
Viendo los comentarios encontré dos soluciones, las cuales son las siguientes:

**Desde `command prompt`.**

Se ingresa a `MySQL` con el comando:

```
mysql -u usuario -p
```

Les pedirá la contraseña de ese usuario.

Después modificamos la autentificación del usuario con el siguiente comando:

```
ALTER USER 'yourusername'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'youpassword';
```

Lo anterior lo encontré [Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49194719/authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-cannot-be-loaded).

**Solución desde WorkBench.**

Al ingresar a nuestra conexión en **`WorkBench`** nos dirigimos al apartado **Users and Privilegies.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se selecciona el usuario y se le da clic en la pestaña **Login** después se modifica el apartado ***Authentication Type*** por **`Standard**`.

Comment: Hola Ferny, yo fui directamente al MySQL Workbench, abrí una pestaña nueva de SQL y ahí directamente ejecute el comando que mencionas de esta manera -> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY ''; y después fuí a Users and privileges, seleccioné root y en Authentication Type ya aparecía Standard directamente, después he conectado sin problema desde cualquier IDE, tanto Netbeans como Eclipse,  muchas gracias por el aporte. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

La librería que estas usando es para versiones de mysql 5.x, si tienes otra versión del motor de mysql como las 8.x , en donde cambio el modo de autentificacion, deberás usar la librería para la versión de mysql correspondiente.

De ser la version 8.x y después de actualizar el driver con la librería correspondiente y si quieres dejar la url como texto plano deberás usar lo siguiente en tu conectionString:

```
connDB = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/stockinventory?useSSL=false", "user", "password");
```

Answer (score 1):

Tuve el mismo problema con un software que había hecho antes y no usaba un conector optimo para las ultimas versiones de MySQL, no cambie ningún atributo de la BD respecto al usuario que suele ser root por defecto, al parecer esa configuración:
**caching_sha2_password** debe conservarse así, puesto que hace más segura la Base de Datos y por consiguiente la contraseña del usuario, si esta por su puesto es la última versión de MySQL.

Recomiendo que si ocurre este error, lo mejor es asegurarse de que se esta utilizando un conector actualizado o que sea similar a la versión del motor de base de datos, en mi caso comencé a utilizar la última versión de MySQL WorkBench 8.0.26, para ello busque el conector de la misma versión en la carpeta de MySQL de mi escritorio la ruta fue esta:

C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector J 8.0

La carpeta se llama:

**Connector J 8.0**

y dentro se encuentra el conector con extención (.jar).

En caso de no encontrarlo optar por buscar la version en el repositorio de descargas de MySQL [aquí](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/).

O bien las versiones anteriores dependiendo que versión de motor de BD se use [aquí](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-j/).

Y seleccionar **Platform Independient** para una descarga (.zip) o (.tar).

Espero sirva para casos similares.

Dejo mi archivo de conexión:

```
    package Conexion;
    
    /**
     *
     * @author mcore
     */
    import java.sql.*;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    
    
    public class ConexionBD {
    
        public static String db = "gateway";
        public static String user = "root";
        public static String pass = "root";
        public static String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/gateway";
        //public static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gateway?autoReconnect=true&amp;failOverReadOnly=false&amp;maxReconnects=10&amp;removeAbandonedTimeout=60&amp;testWhileIdle=true&amp;timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=300000";
        public static Connection con;
    
        public static Connection getcon() {
    
            try {
                //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); Esta funciona pero esta deprecada.
                Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"); 
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException  |SQLException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error de Conexión"
                        + ": " + e.getMessage());
            }
            return con;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Hola Eduardo, muchas gracias por el aporte, yo tuve que usar el driver mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar y en mi clase conectar() de tipo Connection puse  Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"); y así me conecta sin problema con MySQL Workbench, un saludo.